# activate $interval with an ng-click function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, setinterval

I am trying to create a count down timer with AngularJS and **$interval service.**

I successfully have created a way to show a time and also have a successful countdown starting from 25 minutes going down to 0.

**However I am finding it difficult to activate $interval inside a function scope?**
In other words I am trying to use $interval only when I call a function that stores it.

In this code snippet, the timer starts when the page loads.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script><!-- AngularJS -->
    <script>
        var myapp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
        myapp.controller('timer',['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval){


          $scope.starttime = 1500000; // 25min in ms
          $scope.format = 'mm:ss'; //minutes and seconds format 

           $interval(function(){
              $scope.starttime;
              $scope.starttime -=1000; //starttime is equal to starttime - 1 second
              /*if($scope.starttime === 0){
                $scope.starttime = 1500000;
              }
              */
            },1000);
            //return start;
          //}; //end starttimer function

          $scope.killtimer = function(){

          }


        }]);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1 ng-controller="timer">{{ starttime | date:format}}</h1> <!-- start time with format filter -->
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="starttimer()">Start</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="killtimer()">End Timer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

However I want  to wrap the $interval inside a $scope.starttimer function so I can call it with ng-click and a button on the DOM. Here is my unsuccessful attempt at that version.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script><!-- AngularJS -->
    <script>
        var myapp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
        myapp.controller('timer',['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval){

          $scope.starttime = 1500000; // 25min in ms
          $scope.format = 'mm:ss'; //minutes and seconds format 
          $scope.starttimer = function($scope){
           $interval(function(){
              $scope.starttime;
              $scope.starttime -=1000; //starttime is equal to starttime - 1 second
              /*if($scope.starttime === 0){
                $scope.starttime = 1500000;
              }
              */
            },1000);
            //return start;
          //}; //end starttimer function

          $scope.killtimer = function(){

          }


        }]);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1 ng-controller="timer">{{ starttime | date:format}}</h1> <!-- start time with format filter -->
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="starttimer()">Start</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="killtimer()">End Timer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

This version doesn't work. The AngularJS breaks!!?? Not sure why.

Here is a link to a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Eo7sBf8rANQyulnC2WG?p=preview)

Comment: The plnkr breaks because this line should not be commented: `//}; //end starttimer function`.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

The main one is the button is not in the scope of the controller.
You put the `ng-controller` on the heading tag. Move `ng-controller` up to a higher level that includes the button.

Missing a closing brace `}`

Remove `$scope.starttime;` inside the interval

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0AlgMzWGQa2zJTz7vL6?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Short and precise answer +1. You beat me by few seconds :D

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you so much for the explanation and Demo. Makes complete sense. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can only call those functions on `ng-click` that are defined within the controller's scope.

The functions `starttimer()` and `killtimer()` are defined in the controller `timer` but *they are not within the block enclosed by `ng-controller`*(notice you have used `ng-controller` on `<h1>` so thats the only place where you can use the functions).

Simply move `ng-controller` to the element that also covers the two buttons

```
  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="timer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1 >{{ starttime | date:format}}</h1> <!-- start time with format filter -->
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="starttimer()">Start</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="killtimer()">End Timer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Also, you are not closing the `$scope.starttimer()` function properly. Make sure you uncomment the line `}; //end starttimer function`

```
  $scope.starttimer = function(){
    alert('started')
   $interval(function(){
      $scope.starttime;
      $scope.starttime -=1000; //starttime is equal to starttime - 1 second
      /*if($scope.starttime === 0){
        $scope.starttime = 1500000;
      }
      */
    },1000);
    //return start;
  }; //end starttimer function
```

Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lEZgKCiFHCT9pjokThvp?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @NLN for checking on my error? I have just checked your solution. I see now what I have done wrong. Thank you for this explanation.